# Alternatives to READ_CALL_LOG for accessing a caller's number?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, google-play-console, caller-id

Due to recent policy changes, it's very difficult to gain permission to use the READ_CALL_LOG permission on Google Play. Our app searches for the incoming caller's number in our app and if there is a match, show Caller ID information inputted in our app. Thus, we are not a default phone app, but just need access to only the incoming caller's number. Are there any alternatives to READ_CALL_LOG to get the caller's number?

Comment: Nope, that's the permission you need.

Comment: Have you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm searching for the answer too. Did you try to make the default call/sms app?

Answer (score 0):

Android 9 introduces the CALL_LOG permission group and moves the READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG, and PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permissions into this group. In previous versions of Android, these permissions were located in the PHONE permission group.

Please go through this link

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all

Answer (score 0):

Here how I have achieved this -

Step 1:
Created a CallActivity and read the all call log in `onCreate` and displayed in listview with a button **Call**.

Step 2: 
When user click on button **Call** this code get fired

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", "1234567890", null));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Step 3:
In AndroidManifest file update this (For newly created activity only - **CallActivity**)

```
<activity
        android:name=".CallActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="voicemail" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

You are done.

I was also able to publish my app in play store with CALL_READ_PERMISSION and filled the google policy form with CALLER ID app section. In my case user authentication required to I push the demo account credentials.